# Minimum size of buttons for mobile APP

Tags: usability, buttons, mobile-application

I am quite new to UXD and UXSE; I have checked previous answers but could not find what I am looking for, so here we go.
I am designing a mobile-application and I was wondering if there is any standard about the size of selection buttons. In particular, is there a minimum size?
Thanks